# How to ignore some route while using ASP.NET Friendly URLs?

Tags: asp.net, routes, friendly-url

I am using ASP.NET Friendly URLs with success, but I need to ignore route for a particular `Foo.aspx` page (because this page needs POST data and once re-routed the POST data is not available anymore in `Page_Load()`!).

It looks like using ASP.NET Friendly URLs discard any attempt to ignore a route. Even the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992982(v=vs.110).aspx) for ignoring route doesn't work once ASP.NET Friendly URLs routing is used:

```
routes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
```

And to ignore route to `Foo.aspx` the code should look like that, isn't it?

```
routes.Ignore("{*fooaspx}", new { fooaspx = @"(.*/)?foo.aspx(/.*)?" });
```

The `Global.asax` code looks like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

    // This doesn't work whether I put this code before or after ASP.NET Friendly URLs code.
    routes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });

    routes.Canonicalize().Lowercase();

    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;   
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
}

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

This question [has been asked on the ASP.NET Friendly URLs codeplex site](https://aspnetfriendlyurls.codeplex.com/workitem/13), but didn't get an answer.

Thanks for your help on this :)

Comment: Its my understanding that _if a physical file exists_, then it takes precedence (over any routing config), so why is it "re-routed"/redirected?

Comment: ASP.NET Friendly URLs code is doing its redirection job fine with all .aspx files that are physical files that exist, including the site\Foo.aspx. For example the url 'Site.com\Foo-Bar.aspx' gets redirected to 'site.com\foo-bar' and Foo-Bar.aspx file exists. How could this explain that routes.Ignore() doesn't work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to Damian Edwards comment, I got this issue completely solved, thanks Damian.

I just need to derive from `WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver` to override the method `ConvertToFriendlyUrl()` to make it no-op when the url match the url I don't want to redirect:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Resolvers;

public class MyWebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver : WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver {
   public MyWebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver() { }

   public override string ConvertToFriendlyUrl(string path) {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) {
         if (path.ToLower().Contains("foo")) { // Here the filter code
            return path;
         }
      }
      return base.ConvertToFriendlyUrl(path);
   }
}
```

Then in `Global.asax` the code now looks like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.Canonicalize().Lowercase();
    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings, 
                              new IFriendlyUrlResolver[] { 
                                 new MyWebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver() });
}

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This was interesting - had to tinker :) In my comment above, what I was trying to say was "no need to ignore".

I was "right" and "wrong".

- right: no need to ignore
- wrong: not because of what I stated (re: physical file), but rather, by *not invoking the redirect in the first place*.

This will bomb out (redirect will occur, POST data is lost):

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Go" PostBackUrl="~/Target.aspx" />
```

This will be good (you will get POST data, no redirect occurs):

```
 <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Go" PostBackUrl="~/Target" />
```

The difference? I'm **not** asking FriendlyUrls to "re-route" anything in the 2nd option. In the first option, I'm asking for an "aspx" file, so FriendlUrls will dutifully do its purpose for being and "handle" it (and do a permanent redirect to a "friendly url" which is a GET and there goes all the POSTed data).

- Inspect request in 1st option (**target.aspx**):
  [image: target.aspx request]
- Inspect request in 2nd option (extensionless, **target**):
  [image]

This was a clue:

```
var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

And it does what it says, "do a permanent redirect" (to a "friendly url")...when "necessary" (if an "aspx" file is requested). You can tinker with this with any page in your WebForms site

- if you request `foo.aspx` you will see a Redirect (to `foo`)
- if you request `foo`, no Redirect

You can also comment out

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

and things will work but sort of defeats the purpose of FriendlyUrls...

Thinking about it, it makes perfect sense. There is no need to "redirect" on *every* request (ugh for performance), rather only if/when necessary...

Hth....

Comment: Thanks! Your solution will be a nice Plan-B. The source that is posting-back to Site.com\Foo.aspx has the url hardcoded for now. We can change the source url to Site.com\Foo but this will come with a price. Still why the route.Ignore() doesn't work? Is there another redirection alternative? I tried also redirecting Foo.aspx to Foo in Web.config\system.webServer\rewrite\rules with no luck, the POST data get lost here too.

Comment: The ignore route doesn't work because our redirect logic happens in an HTTP Module, not in the route itself. This so we can handle redirects of default documents (e.g. Default.aspx).

As to ignoring a specific path, this is likely possible if you derive from and customize WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver and override a few methods, making them no-op when the path matches what you want to ignore. Then pass an instance in to the overload of EnableFriendlyUrls that accepts an IFriendlyUrlResolver as a parameter.