# RouteCollection.ignore doesn't work

Tags: c#, routes

I use RouteCollection with FriendlyUrlSettings to remove aspx from being shown... so now every time someone access my site, instead of display www.mysite.com/login.aspx , it will display www.mysite.com/login

But I have a problem where an old app needs to access a page, and it's already hard-coded inside the app to access www.mysite.com/service/AuthenticateUser.aspx page. But because of the friendlyurl, the app doesn't work.

So I added this line

```
routes.Ignore("Service/AuthenticateUser.aspx");
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything. Every time I access the page Service/AuthenticateUser.aspx , it will still redirect me to Service/AuthenticateUser only

Comment: Put it at top of the list.

Comment: @HarveySpecter did that, still doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460798/how-to-ignore-some-route-while-using-asp-net-friendly-urls